# Support url for app submission in appstore

Tags: ios, app-store

Is support url necessary for app submission in the Appstore? I am registered as an individual developer and i don't have a web page for support url. What can i do?

Comment: Not exactly a programming question , but I think you can make a blog for free and make that your support page. It would also be good for marketing your app ( posting photos of the app on the blog , describing it , videos , etc) and then share it on facebook , twitter , etc

Comment: How to make a blog? Does creating a blog costs money?

Comment: How can i use blogger to get url for app submission support url?

Comment: In my comment I specified "for free" ( aka "cost free" , "no money required") . You can go to wordpress.com  , register and start building your blog. For free. There are other services like this too ( blogger , blogspot , etc) Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 21):

The support url is now required.  You can make a free account at a site like:

http://www.wordpress.com/

or similar.

Answer (score 12):

I would create a free page at [github pages](https://pages.github.com/). Simple and straight forward. If you need something simple it is the perfect choice.

Comment: From Apple: "The support URL specified in your app’s metadata, https://github.com/myUser/myRepo/issues, does not properly navigate to the intended destination."

Comment: @Dani With Github pages you can create static website like this:
amanokerim.github.io

Answer (score 10):

Apple provides a bit more info in their help docs:

> The support website you plan to provide for users who have questions
> regarding the app. The support URL must lead to actual contact
> information so that users can reach you regarding app issues, general
> feedback, and feature enhancement requests. Specify entire URL,
> including the protocol, as in http://support.example.com.
>
> Only customers who purchase the app can see the Support URL on the App
> Store.
>
> This property is required and can be localized.

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devf29afbb74

Comment: "Only customers who purchase the app can see the Support URL on the App Store." So if my app is free, why do I need it?

Comment: @genericUser Because Apple also consider the free application as a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be fine, I had the same problem like this. I have submitted the app without the link and it got accepted and after that i have edited the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a facebook page for you app with necessary information and submit it.

I've used facebook page for both marketing url and support url.

Answer (score 0):

I use Sites.google.com, it gives you a lot of templates, easy to edit and it publishes site for free and with a single click.